# Using System.Dynamic.Linq in Projections

Tags: vb.net, linq

I try to use Dynamic linq in projections , but it seems that doesn't work.
This is the code :

```
 Dim mylist = (From t In context.Myobj1s.Where("it.id =5") Select New With { _
         .Parent = t, _
        .child1 = t.ch1s.AsQueryable.Where("vl1 >=7"), _
    .child2 = t.ch2s.Asqueryable.Where("quantity <=4") _
     }).ToList
```

This produce an error :

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MyEnt.Ch1] Where[Ch1](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Myent.Ch1], System.String, System.Object[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

What can I do ?
Thank you !

---

Using a suggestion , I try to use predicateBuilder . This is the Code :

```
Dim pred1 = PredicateBuilder.True(Of Myobj1)()
Dim pred2 = PredicateBuilder.True(Of ch1)()
Dim pred3 = PredicateBuilder.True(Of ch2)()
pred1=pred1.And(Function(t) t.id=5)
pred2=pred2.And(Function(t1) t1.vl1>=7)
pred3=pred3.And(Function(t2) t2.quantity<=4)
Dim mylist = (From t In context.Myobj1s.Where(pred1)Select New With { _
         .Parent = t, _
        .child1 = t.ch1s.Where(pred2), _
    .child2 = t.ch2s.Where(pred3) _
     }).ToList
```

Now I'm getting this error in design time :

```
Error   103 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Where' can be called with these arguments:
Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Func(Of ch1, Integer, Boolean)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of ch1)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Value of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of Dyqani.FatD_item, Boolean))' cannot be converted to 'System.Func(Of Myent.ch1, Integer, Boolean)'.
Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Func(Of ch1, Boolean)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of ch1)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Value of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of MyEnt.ch1, Boolean))' cannot be converted to 'System.Func(Of MyEnt.ch1, Boolean)'.
Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As String, ParamArray values() As Object) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of ch1)' defined in 'System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicQueryable': Value of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of myent.ch1, Boolean))' cannot be converted to 'String'
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: You might want to try [Predicate Builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) instead.

Comment: But what's wrong with my code ?

Comment: My guess is that Linq to Entities can't convert your Dynamic Linq into expression trees that are compatible with Entity Framework.  There are several expressions that are not supported by EF, even without Dynamic Linq in the picture; see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738550(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: The problem is with .child1 and .child2 , because the first part  for .parent is working correctly.

Comment: What are the `AsQueryable` methods there for?  You're calling `ToList` at the end, so it's clear that you don't need lazy execution.

Comment: Without the Asqueryable() methods , the where (...) doesn't support string and produce error in design time.

Comment: I would try Predicate Builder.  You might get the same error, but it's still worth a shot.

Comment: So you're not sure that predicate builder can resolve that ? It's there a n example with predicate builder for a similar case ? So Predicate builder with Projections ?

Comment: It would take you 5 to 10 minutes to write some code and find out.  The problem is, it would take me much longer to set up EF, some tables, etc. to match your environment.

Comment: Sorry , what should I include in order to use predicate builder. I try to write: Dim predict as PredicateBuilder.False(Of Myobj1) but it's unknown type.

Comment: Get [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx).  It includes special support for Entity Framework.

Comment: @Robert - Please see the results in edited post.

Comment: Don't use "EDIT:" in your posts.  This isn't a forum.

Comment: That's a compile error.  Which line of code is causing it?

Comment: .child1 = t.ch1s.Where(pred2),  The same error is in the line .child2 = t.ch2s.Where(pred3)

Comment: Well, you need to get the method signature right.

Comment: The compiler error is saying that you're calling a method with a signature that doesn't match the signature of any of the overloads for that method.  Do you know what a signature is?  An overload?

Comment: It's strange but if I add the Asqueryable like this : .chld1=t.ch1s.Asqueryable.Where(pred2)  the compile error is disappear , but I get a runtime error : The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

Comment: I suspect that if you materialize the result into a collection without the projection first (with ToList or AsEnumerable), and then run your projection on that, it will work because you're no longer involving Entity Framework or SQL Server at that point.

Comment: But I want to run only one read from database with the final query.

Comment: We can't always get everything we want.  Try that first.  If it works, then we know.

Comment: it's the same problem

Comment: I just add this code before the projections : mylist=context.Myobj1s.Tolist. and after in projections I use ....from t in mylist .....

Comment: I try also to use the AsExpandable as is described here :http://felipecsl.com/blog/2009/08/13/the-linq-expression-node-type-invoke-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities/  but it's the same problem

Comment: If you did this correctly, you should have had to put `AsQueryable` after each `ToList` (since `IEnumerable` apparently doesn't support the overloads we want).

Comment: I'm going to set this up in Visual Studio and see if I can reproduce the problem, but it's going to take awhile.

Comment: ok , I think to open a new question regarding this issue with  Predicatebuilder , because I think I can get more help.

Comment: As you wish.  Just try to keep in mind that Stack Overflow isn't a diagnostic tool or a place to get extended consultation or troubleshooting.  It is a question and answer site, nothing more.  I'm setting it up in my environment because I find the problem an interesting one.

Comment: I open a new question , because this question is started as a question regarding another problem , but of course if you have time I'm waiting your results.Thank you !

Comment: Show me what your tables look like.

Comment: Myobj1: ID(integer , Primary key ) , name(string)  , type(integer)

Comment: ch1: Id (integer , Primary key ) , vl1 (integer) , ParID ( integer , foreign key)

Comment: ch2 : Id (integer , Primary key ) ,quantity (integer) , ParID ( integer , foreign key)

Comment: What does ParID link to?

Comment: is the filed that has the parent ID ( Myobj.id)